# Create an array of Rectangles : Opencv , Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, contour, bounding-box

I have contours which are extracted from findcontours() , Now I want to create an array of all the boundingrects of contours.

```
int area,total=0;

for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    area = (int) Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));

    if(area>4600 && area<5100)
    {
        Rect abc = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));                          
    }
}
```

Here it is saving only 1 contour in Rect , I want an array of Rect of all contours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be better:

```
int area,total=0;
List<Rect> contourRects = new ArrayList();

for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    area = (int) Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));

    if(area>4600 && area<5100)
    {
        contourRects.add(Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i)));                          
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct (+1), but you should explain to OP what he was getting wrong.